# vba: object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

i am doing this:

```
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

and getting the above mentioned error.

please note that this has worked for many months and now all of a sudden it does not workl

what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a workbook open in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps no workbook is active at all? Is your code running from a hidden workbook, like the personal workbook?